# How to parse object (and its elements) from ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here's my issue.  I'm making an ajax request to obtain an object from a controller.  The object (or something) is being brought back, but I don't know how to access the attributes of that object being brought back. The object is of type "Address" and thus has attributes like Address.Address1, Address.City, etc. Here is my code: After a button is clicked,

```
function showEditAddress(addressid) {

    $.get("/Website/Accommodation/AddressGet",
        { guid: addressid.toString() },

        function(data) {

             //Get values from variable 'data' such as described above
             //and append to form 'dialog'

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                // autoOpen: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 250
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 250
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Save": {
                        text: "Save",
                        class: "",
                        click: function () {
                             //save form 
                            $(this).dialog("close");

                        }
                    },
                    "Cancel": {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        class: "",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });       
    }
```

Controller action:

```
        public Address AddressGet(string guid)
    {
        Guid g = new Guid(guid);
        return _iCoreRepository.Addresses.Where(p => p.AddressID == g).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't see where you are appending anything to the dialog

Comment: I'm sorry, 'dialog' is the id of a <div> element where my form resides, my problem is not so much the dialog, but the actual data being brought back, I dont know how to manipulate it.

Comment: Start by opening your console and doing console.log(data) or console.dir(data) so that you can see the structure being returned.

Comment: I do have an "alert(data);" and it returns the following:  
'System.Data.Entiy.DynamicProxies.Address_35525777Fe...'

Comment: Then more than likely you aren't returning JSON (or any other useable form of data) from your service. You need your service to return something that javascript can parse into a javascript array/object, such as JSON or XML

Comment: That does sound likely.  What would I need to change in order to return a usable object?

Comment: I don't know, i have little to no knowledge of asp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jose is quite simple. You already answer the question. To get the value of the properties of `Address` you only need put a dot in front of `data` and type de property name. like this:

```
//(....)
function(data) {

    //Get values from variable 'data' such as described above
    //and append to form 'dialog'

    //show address id.
    alert(data.AddressID);
```

Remember that javascript is case sensitive, so you need use upper case to `A` and `ID` in AddressID like you did in C#.

And in controller you need replace the last line to something like this:

```
var address = _iCoreRepository.Addresses.Where(p => p.AddressID == g).SingleOrDefault();
return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

the method must be return `JsonResult`. The method Json serialize the object, in this case address, in a json format before response the data to the client.

If you need the Json method accepts IEnumerables to, like List<> or Array. In javascript your data object will be a lenght property and will acess each element by using indexer like:

```
data[0].AddressID.
```

Comment: How is that going to work, if the alert(data) returns `'System.Data.Entiy.DynamicProxies.Address_35525777Fe...'`? that's a string.

Comment: This is great! I'll try it right now and respond with my results!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning just your `Address` object you can try returning a `JsonResult`.

```
public ActionResult AddressGet(string guid)
{
    Guid g = new Guid(guid);
    var address = _iCoreRepository.Addresses.Where(p => p.AddressID == g).SingleOrDefault();
    return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in your jquery, the returned `data` is your address object and you can access the fields as they appear in your C# class:

```
function showEditAddress(addressid) {

    $.get("/Website/Accommodation/AddressGet",
        { guid: addressid.toString() },

        function(data) {

            //Get values from variable 'data' such as described above
            //and append to form 'dialog'
            //Access it like: data.Address1, data.City etc...

        });       
    }
}
```